# Auto-commit to SVN with Java

Tags: java, svn, commit

I run a lot of my projects for work using

```
java name.java
```

I was wondering if there was a way to add a hook to it where it would commit to SVN once that command is ran?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Ant and Maven are preferred, but if you insist on doing it manually:

Linux: `java Some.java && svn commit -m "baz" [..other args]`

Windows: `java Some.java & svn commit [..args]`

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to hook the 'java' executable itself.

What you want is a build system like [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) (you may or may not be familiar with the very old school [make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/)) - They allow innumerable actions before and after compilation, including building distribution binary, source control commits, documentation generation, testing...  They will change your life.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a shutdownHook to Java Code which you like to run

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
  ....do something...
}
```

But i wouldn't recommend that...and i think you don't need it...

What i don't understand is what you like to reach with that automatic commit ? Which reason do you have for such a thing?